# resize contact image from BufferedInputStream

Tags: android, bitmap, inputstream

I'm trying to check the size of a fetched contact image and resize if needed. I'm using the suggested by the official developer android site pattern      https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html, with some small changes. This is my code

```
private static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight)
{
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth)
    {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth)
        {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromBufferedStream(BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws IOException
{
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, new Rect(), options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream, new Rect(), options);
}
```

I'm calling the decodeSampledBitmapFromBufferedStream method from inside a cursor (I don't really know if it matters). My problem is that the outHeight and outwidth of the options object are always 0 and the return bitmap is null. I think it has something to do with the re usage of the bufferedInoutStream object, but I don't know how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream once it's position moved, you usually cannot go back (unless it has a rewind method, like a filestream). You can either close the stream, and open a new one, or else read the complete stream the first time into a byte array, and use `decodeByteArray` both times instead.